# how to merge front end website and admin panel in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new in ReactJs and I've created a front end website using html template. Now I want to merge it with admin panel, I've downloaded html template and tried to combine with Front end website. But Admin's CSS are clashing with front end's CSS files

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to implement **CSS Modules**, with the help of Webpack or Browserify.

CSS Modules allows the scoping of CSS by automatically creating a unique classname of the format [filename]_[classname]__[hash].

Implementing CSS Modules either in the admin panel or the front would remove the CSS style conflicts.